# perforce eclipse plugin preference to checkout a file when editing

Tags: perforce

I'm new to perforce. we integerated the perforce eclipse plugin in PC for the development. We use eclipse plugin for all the P4 operation. I downloaded my workspace code into my local PC and using eclipse for the development.When i edit the file using eclipse, i would like eclipse plugin to checkout the file automatically.
Looks like there is a preference already under team->perforce Enable support for Workbench save operations.

I tried this option but its not working for me. is it the right option?

Could someone please help me.

Thanks,
Venkataraman

Answer (score 2):

To get auto-checkout enable Team -> Perforce | Enable support for Workbench edit, delete, and refactoring options.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Windows->Preferences ->Perforce

Therein check the following:

```
When adding a new file:
Mark for add
```

Also check the following:

```
Show changelist selection dialog when marking files for add,cehcing out, and marking for delete
Show changelist selection dialog when refactoring files
Enable support for Workbench edit,delete,rename and refactoring operations
```